# Eclipse Rich Client platform with treeViewer

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, rcp, treeviewer

I want to create a small desktop app with the purpose of querying a database (MongoDB database) and I want my app to show databases and tables list in a tree view, on the left pannel for example:

```
database1       
        -table1
        -table2
database2
        -table1
        -table2
        -table3
```

and in the right panel I want to display the data in a table. When the user select the table the data should be displayed in the table.

I managed to display the database list but not the tables.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this is far too broad. You are asking for most of a book. Try a tutorial such as [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) or even buy Lars Vogel's book mentioned in that article.

Comment: thank you i'll check it out